# manipulating nsmutabledata

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdata

Hi I am trying to create a packet that I want to send over the network to a server, I have pretty much got the packet sorted however its missing a length identifier which I need to calculate at the end of my method and add into the packet.

The packet structure is like this

- leading value identifier (UInt16)
- content size (UInt32)
- packet Content (string)

currently my method looks something like this

```
- (NSMutableData *) addRegCode
{
    //Supply some default string for testing
    NSString *regCode = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"abcd1"];
    //create NSData object
    NSData *registrationCodeData = [regCode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableData * RegistrationCodeMutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; //send this object
    //create leading value
    UInt16 leadingValue = 8;
    NSData * leadingValueData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:&leadingValue length:sizeof(leadingValue)];

    //append data to mutableData
    [RegistrationCodeMutableData appendData:leadingValueData];
    [RegistrationCodeMutableData appendData:registrationCodeData];

    return RegistrationCodeMutableData;
}
```

what I would like to know is how to calculate the size of **registrationCodeData** and then add it between where I append **leadingValueData & registrationCodeData**

I think I have to be using **dataWithBytes:length:** but I'm not 100% sure of how to use this

Comment: So I have this ** NSData *registrationCodeSize = [NSData dataWithBytes:registrationCodeData length:???];** however, im not sure what to put in the question marks for the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it.

```
NSUInteger size = [registrationCodeData length];
NSData *sizeData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&size length:sizeof(size)];
[RegistrationCodeMutableData appendData:leadingValueData];
[RegistrationCodeMutableData appendData:sizeData];
[RegistrationCodeMutableData appendData:registrationCodeData];
```

also of note using capital letters to start variable names is a little atypical and can be confusing to read!

Comment: thanks for that, yep I normally start my varaible without caps.. but these are request names to my db and wanted them to be identifiable.. but i think i will just change to non caps.. thanks for the help worked perfectly.